# How to add a cron via ssh?

Tags: ssh, cron

I want to create a crontab to execute a php script, however I have to setup the cron via ssh and have absolutely no idea how to go about it. I've tried searching however the results always come back for executing ssh via a cron and not how to set one up.

Can someone point me in the right direction to some documentation?

Many thanks.

Comment: What version of cron is it?  Are you running a version of linux where you are able to simply publish a file to /etc/cron.d/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crontab -e` is used to edit the cron entries for the current user. See the `crontab(1)` and `crontab(5)` man pages for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Use ssh to gain access to the system you want to edit the crontab on. If required use `su` to change to an appropriate account

Then something like

```
export EDITOR=vi
crontab -e
```

see the [**crontab(5)**](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) man page for info on the file itself and the [**crontab(1)**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) man page for info on the crontab  program